# I've a table with Map as column data type, how can I explode it to generate 2 columns, one for map and one for key?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

```
Hive Table: (Name_Age: Map[String, Int] and ID: Int)
```

```
+---------------------------------------------------------++------+
|                  Name_Age                               ||  ID  | 
+---------------------------------------------------------++------+
|"SUBHAJIT SEN":28,"BINOY MONDAL":26,"SHANTANU DUTTA":35  ||  15  |
|"GOBINATHAN SP":35,"HARSH GUPTA":27,"RAHUL ANAND":26     ||  16  |
+---------------------------------------------------------++------+
```

I've exploded the Name_Age column into multiple Rows:

```
def toUpper(name: Seq[String]) =  (name.map(a => a.toUpperCase)).toSeq

sqlContext.udf.register("toUpper",toUpper _)

var df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT toUpper(name) FROM namelist").toDF("Name_Age")

df.explode(df("Name_Age")){case org.apache.spark.sql.Row(arr: Seq[String]) => arr.toSeq.map(v => Tuple1(v))}.drop(df("Name_Age")).withColumnRenamed("_1","Name_Age")
```

```
+-------------------+
|     Name_Age      |
+-------------------+
|  [SUBHAJIT SEN,28]|
|  [BINOY MONDAL,26]|
|[SHANTANU DUTTA,35]|
| [GOBINATHAN SP,35]|
|   [HARSH GUPTA,27]|
|   [RAHUL ANAND,26]|
+-------------------+
```

But I want to explode and create 2 rows: Name and Age

```
+-------------------+-------+
|       Name        |  Age  |
+-------------------+-------+
|  SUBHAJIT SEN     |  28   |
|  BINOY MONDAL     |  26   | 
|SHANTANU DUTTA     |  35   |
| GOBINATHAN SP     |  35   |
|   HARSH GUPTA     |  27   |
|   RAHUL ANAND     |  26   |
+-------------------+-------+
```

Could any one please help with the explode code modification?

Answer (score 4):

All you need here is to drop `toUpper` call `explode` function:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.explode

val df = Seq((Map("foo" -> 1, "bar" -> 2), 1)).toDF("name_age", "id")
val exploded = df.select($"id", explode($"name_age")).toDF("id", "name", "age")
exploded.printSchema

// root
//  |-- id: integer (nullable = false)
//  |-- name: string (nullable = false)
//  |-- age: integer (nullable = false)
```

You can convert to upper case using built-in functions afterwards:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.upper

exploded.withColumn("name", upper($"name"))
```